# Devise show User

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, user-profile

Despite all the questions and solutions I've read so far, nothing has worked for me yet here showing a signed in user profile page with devise. I've tried a number of things in my routes as well. My error is currently shows - "Couldn't find User without an ID". I'm a newbie with devise so while I like it, it has been a bit frustrating. Any help would be appreciated. Still very much in the learning stages. Thanks.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show]
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get 'users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
  resources :user
    match 'users/show', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'



  root to: 'pages#home'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match 'users/show', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
```

This line suggests that it will route the url `users/show` to your controller#action `users#show`.   And inside your controller you are looking for the user with the id of `params[:id]`.  Except, you are never passing in an id parameter.  Typically, the id is passed in the url (ie `users/show/:id`).  That is the cause of your error.

The solution depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  You could either pass the id through the url, or if you want the `users/show` to show only the logged in user profile, I would add a controller action (called profile for example) and then set/get a session variable with the user id and redirect to user's view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your second option is what I want to do. So basically add an action called profile in users controller that uses the current session to render a view? Should I be using the devise current_user method?

Comment: I forgot about `current_user`.  You could check if the id has been passed (`params.has_key?"id"`) and if so render the @user found in the database or if not then render the view using current_user.  All without modifying your routes or adding an additional controller action (you will need to modify your `show` action, however).  That is probably the best action